# C# ASP.NET web application custom error page generates "Authorization Required" dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set up error handling within my C# asp.net web application and I'm experiencing this strange phenomenon. On every page before it loads, an "Authentication Required" dialog box appears asking for a "Username" & "Password". However, when I select cancel, the box disappears and the page loads. The strange part is that it's seemingly related to my custom error page along with the code redirect I've recently added for my application.

This is the code below I have in my Web.config file

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On"></customErrors>
  ...
</system.web>
```

Here's the error.aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Error.aspx.cs" Inherits="Error"  MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"%>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" 
runat="server">
<h2>Application Error</h2>
<h3>An unexpected error has occured on our website. Please contact the support team for assistance.</h3>
</asp:Content>
```

When I comment out the  piece in the Web.config file the dialog box doesn't appear. Not sure as to why those are related. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you have selected the Windows authentication in the web.config file. check you web.config file for element like this "<authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate="true"/>"

Comment: You could debug why the other page is shown. This explanation is not really good.

Comment: I'm not entirely what you're meaning by other page here. All the pages are loading but this "Authentication Required" dialog box is shown first before the page requested by the user can take any action on said page. For instance, if they go to the "order.aspx" page, the dialog box is shown, user clicks cancel, then the order page is loaded. Same goes for every web page in my app. This is only happening when the <customErrors> piece is in my web.config code for redirecting errors to my custom error page. Does that help?